# Re-assigning the meshes vertex groups the way they where before joining all the meshes

Tags: mesh, rigging

I like to create my characters in Blender with lots of individual meshes instead of just one large.

However, when I am finished, I need just one mesh, as I use the result for gaming.

The problem is that rigging and posing works fine, but then when I select all meshes and join them.. all binding is gone. (I can re-assign manually, but it takes for ever)

I'm fairly new to all this, but I can see that the combined mesh has been arranged in vertex groups, so the information is still there..

Do you know a way of re-assigning the meshes vertex groups the way they where before joining all the meshes?

Or joining while keeping the binding?

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: If all the parts have distinct materials then you can use the Materials Property editor in Edit mode to select the parts individually and reassign the vertex groups.  Make sure that the materials are assigned when the Vertex groups are still working and selectable. If errors show up I'd make sure all the groups are unassigned first then try again.

Comment: Thanks a lot MarcClintDion! Thank you :) This wort of gives me issues later in the flow, when I want to have the complete mesh using only one material.. but I think I should be able to make a work flow to fit this. THanks.